# "New Folder with Selection" question

Tags: macos, finder, shortcut-menu

I'm looking for a way to change the minimum number of files required to 1 so I can make a folder from a single selected file rather than having to have 2 selected before it becomes available.

To see what I mean...

Go to Finder
Select any two (or more) files in the same folder or the Desktop.
right click on the selection
you will see a choice "New Folder with Selection (x items)"

I would like to be able to only select one and have that choice appear.

Thanks.

Comment: “New Folder with Selection” also appears in the File menu, where it has the shortcut Command-Control-N. However, when only one file is selected, the menu item is disabled (greyed out).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest creating a new Service in Automator. Adding a service to the finder will add it in the contextual menu !

1. Create new service
2. Servicce receives selected  in
3. Add a run AppleScript Action
4. Paste the following code

Using just a simple AppleScript

```
on run {input, parameters}

tell application "Finder"
    set thePath to first item of input
    set ParentFolder to container of thePath
    set theFolder to (make new folder at ParentFolder)

    repeat with aFIle in input #For each file in input 
        move aFIle to theFolder
    end repeat
end tell
```

end run

Save it and enjoy the new service by selecting your new service in the contextual menu of one of your folders.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in Mac OSX Mountain Lion too, and scoured high and low to find it. Just wanted to share it with you.

Select a single file in Finder, -paste- into the Applescript Editor, and run it. It'll give you a dialog to input the name for the -new folder-.

```
try
    tell application "Finder" to set the this_folder to (folder of the front window) as alias
on error -- no open windows
    set the this_folder to path to desktop folder as alias

end try

tell application "Finder"
    set selected_items to selection

    set thefoldername to text returned of (display dialog "Folder name:" default answer "new folder")


    set theFolder to (make new folder at this_folder with properties {name:thefoldername}) --added "set theFolder to.."

    repeat with x in selected_items
        move x to theFolder --changed the variable from "thefoldername" to "theFolder"
    end repeat

end tell
```

Answer (score -1):

I do not believe there is a way to change that. However, you can hit <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to create a new folder, and then drag the file in.